# Call a web service from a console application passing parameters

Tags: web-services, windows-services, console-application

I am trying to figure out the best way to call a web service on a schedule.  I have been doing research for longer than I want to admit and just need some thoughts on the best way to do this, and how to start.

I have a asmx web service that I need to call every morning at a specific time to run some import processes in my application.  I don't need to pass anything to it and I don't (necessarily) need to get any results back from the web service.

A lot of what I find on the internet is older technology and I am having trouble implementing any of it in my .NET 4.0/4.5 applications.  I am totally lost and just need some direction to make sure I am not going about this completely wrong.  I have always worked with web apps and have never done anything with Windows services or anything like them.

I was looking into Windows Services but was not having any luck.  Before I fight my way through them I wanted to make sure I was even headed down the right direction.  All I need to do is call this web service on a schedule from a Windows app/service/etc.

Thoughts?

EDIT**

OK, for the time being I have decided to go with a console app and have one working to call the web service.  I know I initially said I didn't care about passing parameters to the web service, but now I have decided that it would be a nice addition.

This is what I currently have, but I cannot figure out how to pass parameters for the life of me.

```
    Dim sSource As String
    Dim sLog As String
    Dim sEvent As String

    sSource = "Import Project Information"
    sLog = "Application"
    sEvent = "Import Started"

    If Not EventLog.SourceExists(sSource) Then
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog)
    End If

    EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent, EventLogEntryType.Information, 0)

    Dim WebService As New Web_Service.ImportProjectInfo
    Dim results As Boolean = WebService.Import()
    Console.WriteLine(results)

    If results = True Then
        sEvent = "Import Successful"
        EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent, EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit, 1)
    Else
        sEvent = "Import Failed"
        EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent, EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit, 999)
    End If
```

Comment: Use a timer in a Winform?  You could even get fancy and make it a Tray application.

Comment: I would do that, however, I have never worked with WinForms and I need this to be a simple solution so I can move on.  I don't need a lot of bells and whistles.  What you are suggesting sounds cool... just a bit out of my skill set right now :(

Comment: If you want to pass parameters to the web service, shouldn't your web method accept parameters of those types? Your console application can have some logic to pass values for those parameters in the web method. May be reading values from a file?

Comment: @AshishGupta - That is what I ended up finding.  I didn't want to change my web service to add the parameters until I found the way to pass those parameters.  I didn't realize that the code I was writing was aware that I didn't have those parameters in the web service yet.  Once I added them in the web service I was able to pass without any trouble at all... it is the easy stuff that drives us crazy!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the easy stuff that drives us crazy!!!!!

I didn't want to change my web service to add the parameters until I found the way to pass those parameters.  I didn't realize that the code I was writing was aware that I didn't have those parameters in the web service yet.  Once I added them in the web service I was able to pass without any trouble at all...

Ashish Gupta ended up mentioning this in one of the comments not too long after I finally realized this.  I am embarrassed to admit this now that this one issue caused me so much trouble... and work.

Basically by doing this once the Web Reference was updated.

```
Dim results As Boolean = WebService.Import("something to pass", "something else")
```

To go back to my original question, I also ended up switching to a Windows Service and I am happy with that once I worked all my issues out.  It seems to me to be the most robust option with the easiest setup/portability.

Comment: Glad to help. Nice to see that you used Windows service. Far more scalable solution than a task scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Windows Task Scheduler, it has many, many options for scheduling, i.e. system startup, at a scheduled time, etc.

Comment: I am ok with using task scheduler, but I need something to actually call the web service, that can't be done (that I am aware of) natively with the task scheduler.

Comment: So you need an .EXE that calls the web service and runs your import processes?

Comment: Kinda - All the .exe needs to do is call the web service, the web service processes everything and just returns a true/false.  I have since posting this question come up with a console app that will do this and is working at a basic level.  Now I just would like to be able to pass parameters to the web service which I am having trouble doing. (question has been updated)